# How many ways are there for an order for $10$ men to choose from $30$ drinks at a bar if every one chooses only one drink?

Tags: combinatorics

How can I find out how many ways there are for $10$ guys at a bar to choose from the $30$ drinks on the menu if every one chooses only one drink.

Note that more than one guy can choose the same drink.

The answer I have is $\binom{39}{29}$, but I'm not sure it's the correct answer since the number is very big.

Comment: But what did you... oh trite, this is getting too old.

Comment: To finish @ParclyTaxel's thought, what have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have the answer (39 choose 29) but this number is huge.. i am not sure if it is correct

Comment: Please edit your question to tell *what* you have tried so far, and where you are stuck. If you simply want your work checked, please provide it in the question as well.

Comment: That number is not huge **enough**.  A single person could choose any one of the 30 drinks some there are 30 choices.  Another person could also choose 30 drinks so together there are $30(30)= 30^2$ possibilities.  Including a third person, there are $30^3$ possibilities.  Get the idea?